# Why does my lotus plant look like this?

Tags: diagnosis, flowers

I was wondering why are the leaves dying some information:

1. I have tuff soil spread around the large container and the seeds buried.
2. The plant sees direct sunlight most of the day.
3. I have 3 rosy barb fish swimming around.
4. I change the water weekly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what should I do regarding this?

Comment: Why do you change the water weekly? Do you treat or condition the water before adding it. Depending on your water supplier, your water may contain chlorine which is not good for plants. The water may have incompatible ph level. etc. etc.

Comment: Fertilizer? Even water plants need NPK.